# Hyper-V Failing to create new VM with error 0x80070531

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

Running Windows 2012 R2 Datacenter, with Hyper-V role installed, domain joined, domain account is both a local admin and a hyper-v admin.

If I try to create a new virtual machine (either via UI, or powershell) I get the following error:

```
The Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management service encountered an unexpected error: This user isn't allowed to sign in to
this computer. (0x80070531).
```

This seems very odd to me since I'm not doing this remotely. Does anyone have any clues as to what is going on? (as a google/bing/duckduckgo search didn't return anything)

I've tried removing and reinstalling the Hyper-V Role (with required reboots), but the error persists.

Comment: Thoughts:  What account is the Hyper-V VMM service running as? Host is joined to domain, is the account in question 1 a domain account? If so, what domain groups is it a member of? Since the error relates to permissions, I'm not surprised it persists after reinstall.